# Converting time zone of Rails ActiveRecord timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timezone

I extended the Time class in my Rails projects so I can easily get the time in NYC:

**/lib/extensions.rb** .

```
class Time
  # Get NYC time:
  def nyc
    self.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
  end
end
```

Testing it out, looks good:

```
time_a = Time.now.utc.nyc
=> Sun, 21 Apr 2019 18:42:12 EDT -04:00
```

The problem is when I pull timestamps from the DB:

```
time_b = object.created_at.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Sun, 21 Apr 2019 17:22:04 EDT -04:00
time_c = object.created_at.nyc
=> Sun, 21 Apr 2019 17:22:04 UTC +00:00
```

Super confused. Converting the timestamp to EDT works when I use in_time_zone in the console, but not when I use the extension? Even though my extension method works on Time objects I create in console? What's happening here?

---

(**Note:** Time instances in Rails are in fact instances of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. "TimeWithZone instances implement the same API as Ruby Time instances, so that Time and TimeWithZone instances are interchangeable." - [ActiveSupportTimeWithZone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html))

Comment: `created_at` is `TimeWithZone`, is that playing a role in this?

Comment: Yes they all are TimeWithZone, but that's supposedly [interchangeable with Time in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html), (`inv.created_at.is_a?(Time)
=> true`) and I've always just extended Time before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to patch ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instead of Time, e.g.

```rb
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def nyc
    in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
  end
end

Time.zone.now.nyc # => Mon, 22 Apr 2019 06:44:41 EDT -04:00
User.last.created_at.nyc # => Sun, 21 Apr 2019 13:34:45 EDT -04:00
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

(edit: I previously said "DateTime" instead of "ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone")

Comment: thanks, should have tested it, works with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Comment: Thank you, this does in fact work, though I'm going to leave this question open a little longer as I'm still confused as to why this particular patch necessitates extending `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, when normally extending `Time` is all that's required.

Comment: rails doesn't use `Time` directly (as it's linked to the local time of your machine) but does things like `Time.zone` (e.g. `Time.zone.now`) to get the UTC time (that is what is stored in the database). also `in_time_zone` is defined by active support and returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. personally I would make a zone name alias for nyc, e.g. doing `in_time_zone('nyc')` (this assumes you set your rails time zone to UTC which is the default)